# Aws Lambda call to external api after callback

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function that sends http call to a API(Let's say `'A'`). After getting response from `'A'` Immediately return the stuff's to the caller i.e., `(callback(null, success))` within 10secs. Then save the Data fetched from API `'A'` to My External API(Let's Say `'B'`).

I tried like below but Lambda waits until event loop is empty(It is waiting for the response from second http call).

I doesn't want to set the eventLoopWaitEmpty to false since it freezes the eventloop and Execute next time when invoked.

```
request.get({url: endpointUrlA}, 
  function (errorA, responseA, bodyA) {

     callback(null, "success");

    request.post({url: endpointUrlB,  
          body: bodyA,
          json: true}, function(errorB, responseB, bodyB){

         //Doesn't want to wait for this response
    });

/* Also tried the callback(null, "success"); here too

});
```

Anybody have any thoughts on How can I implement this? Thanks!

`PS - Btw I read the Previous similar questions doesn't seems to clear with those.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a good candidate for breaking up this lambda into two lambdas with some support code.

1. First lambda recieves request to 'A' and places a message onto SQS.  It then returns to the caller the `success` status.
2. A separate process monitors the SQS queue and invokes a second Lambda on it when a message becomes available.

This has several benefits.

Firstly, you no longer have a long-running lambda waiting for a second system that may be down to return.
Secondly, you're doing things asynchronously in the background.

Take a look at [this blog post](https://sbstjn.com/serverless-sqs-worker-with-aws-lambda.html) for an overview of how this could work in practice.

Comment: How about i can invoke another lambda function asynchronously using `invocationType: Event` does the same process in the background. I was wondering if it is an efficient way. Any thoughts would be much helpful